# CLIPS counting facts or template instances that match the pattern

Tags: clips, expert-system

First I declare:

> (deftemplate worker
>     (slot id
>     (type STRING)
>     (default ?DERIVE))
>
> (slot salary
>     (type FLOAT)
>     (default ?DERIVE)))

then I add:

> (assert(worker(id "a")(salary 30.0)))
>
> (assert(worker(id "b")(salary 40.0)))
>
> (assert(worker(id "c")(salary 60.0)))
>
> (assert(worker(id "d")(salary 70.0)))
>
> (assert(worker(id "e")(salary 10.0)))

How can I count how many 'workers' I have?

How can I count for example how many workers have salary over 30?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact-set query functions:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate worker
   (slot id (type STRING) (default ?DERIVE))
   (slot salary (type FLOAT) (default ?DERIVE)))
CLIPS> (assert (worker (id "a") (salary 30.0)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (worker (id "b") (salary 40.0)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (assert (worker (id "c") (salary 60.0)))
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (assert (worker (id "d") (salary 70.0)))
<Fact-4>
CLIPS> (assert (worker (id "e") (salary 10.0)))
<Fact-5>
CLIPS> (find-all-facts ((?f worker)) (> ?f:salary 30.0))
(<Fact-2> <Fact-3> <Fact-4>)
CLIPS> (length$ (find-all-facts ((?f worker)) (> ?f:salary 30.0)))
3
CLIPS> (do-for-all-facts ((?f worker)) (> ?f:salary 30.0) (printout t ?f:id crlf))
b
c
d
CLIPS>
```